# How to derive matched filters for PPM modulation?

Tags: matlab, filters, matched-filter

I am trying to demodulate a PPM signal in MATLAB. My signal is constructed using 2 base functions :

```
% Base function for bit 1 (centered around Tb/4 and has a width Tb/2) :
g1 = @(t) Ag * rectpuls(t - (1/4)*Tb, Tb/2);

% Base function for bit 0 (centered around 3/4*Tb, width Tb/2) :
g0 = @(t) Ag * rectpuls(t - (3/4)*Tb, Tb/2);
```

Which looks like this :

[image: Base functions for PPM modulation]

My signal is composed of many of these pulses according to a data vector. Everything is passed through a AWGN channel and then comes the demodulation part. Matched filters should be time reversed complex conjugate of my basis fonctions, which I created in my code like this :

```
% Matched filter for g0
h0 = @(t) conj(flip(g0(t)));

% Matched filter for g1
h1 = @(t) conj(flip(g1(t)));
```

I then convolve my signal with theses matched filters and compare the output to retrieve my original data vector.

```
% Matched filter outputs
output_h0 = conv(r, h0(t), 'same');
output_h1 = conv(r, h1(t), 'same');

% Demodulate based on the maximum matched filter output
rb = zeros(1, N);
for k = 1:N
    % Decide which bit was transmitted based on the maximum output
    if output_h1(k * Fs) > output_h0(k * Fs)
        rb(k) = 1;
    else
        rb(k) = 0;
    end
end
```

My retrieved data looked wrong so I plotted the matched filters output and saw that it is completely wrong. What did I get wrong with matched filtering ?

[image: Matched filters output]

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach looks correct to me. but your results seem wrong: for example, the output of the second matched filter (g1) starts at 3000; also, the output of both filters goes to zero when the input is still present. I suspect there's a few bugs in your code.

I reproduced your setup in Julia, transmitting the sequence `g1 g1 g0 g0 g1`, and this is the output of each of the matched filters:

[image]

Note that it is not enough to sample the peaks! You need to sample once per second and choose the largest output. Sampling at times `t = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, we obtain the following sequence out of each filter:

```
g0: 0, 0, 1, 1, 0
g1: 1, 1, 0, 0, 1
```

which is exactly what one would expect.

For completeness, here's the matched filter output for the input signal described in the question (`g1 g0 g1 g0 g0 g0 g0 g1 g0 g1`):

[image]

Here is my code:

```
using DSP

Tp = 1.0  # pulse interval

# Define pulse functions
g0(t) = Tp/2 <= t < Tp ? 1.0 : 0.0
g1(t) = 0 <= t < Tp/2 ? 1.0 : 0.0

# received signal
r(t) = g1(t) + g1(t - Tp) + g0(t - 2Tp) + g0(t - 3Tp) + g1(t - 4Tp)

rx = r.(range(-0.5, 6, step = 1/20))
g0p = g0.(range(0, length=20, step = 1/20))
g1p = g1.(range(0, length=20, step = 1/20))

# matched filtering
mf0 = conv(rx, reverse(g0p))
mf1 = conv(rx, reverse(g1p))
```

Comment: Dagnabbit, now it looks like I have to learn **another** programming language. :-D

Comment: @PeterK. :-) The good news is, Julia is likely to be the last language you'll need to learn! (Yes, I'm a big fan)

Comment: @MBaz What's your experience running Julia on GPUs?

Comment: @Envidia It works pretty well; for many applications, just wrap your data in a CUDA type and the GPU is used behind the scenes. See https://juliagpu.org/

Comment: @DanBoschen No, I used a shorter sequence for simplicity. The OP sequence is g1 g0 g1 g0 g0 g0 g0 g1 g0 g1, which I've tested with my code and works fine.

Comment: @MBaz But the received sequence that the OP shows isn’t 1 1 0 0 1 is it? (Or am I interpreting it incorrectly?)

Comment: @DanBoschen I think the OP's received sequence is g1 g1 g0 g1 g0, and then the output stops.

Comment: @MBaz ok I suspect my g1 and g0 correlation outputs are time reversed as if I reverse those it appears to match what you did and confirmed via simulation (which I didn't do). I think this is the correct answer....indeed g0 is zero first so can't start ramping at t=0 as I show. I ama going to delete my answer to not confuse.

Comment: I have been thinking about this over night. @Dan you are correct my output is good for 5 symbols and then stops, it also looks to be the wrong scale if look at the plots. I used a single time vector in this program for the base functions, the matched filters and the signal, could this be the problem ? Should I use a specific time vector for the base functions and the filters ?

Comment: @Aloys I like how MBaz simulated it by convolving the base shape with the entire sequence; this is representative how it would be in the receiver. I don't see a scaling issue in your plot.

Comment: @Dan I tried implementing MBaz solution to my code and I got about the same issue. Assuming the rest of my code is right, the only reason I can think of is that the 'same' parameter in the "conv" matlab command is giving me only the beginning of the output instead of the middle part without the zeros around.

Comment: Yes have you tried it with 'full'? Consider using `filter`, that's another way to get there. But I think MBaz answered your question, right?

Comment: @AloysReant The long pulse vectors along with 'same' explain your result: you're seeing the second half of the bits. I second Dan's recommendation to use 'full' or `filter`.

Comment: @MBaz my code is now working I think it was a bug in the convulotion function or I might not understand how it works but by using the 'full' argument and cuting the zeros myself I got the original data back. Thank you for your help !

Comment: I'm glad you got it working!

Comment: @aloys unless you think this answer is incorrect (I believe it is correct) please mark is as correct to close this out